# How to include jquery plugin in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

i have included jquery cycle plugin in cakephp but slideshow is not working on my website.
i tried adding like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.cycle.all');
?>
```

but is it the way or there is other method?

Comment: where is the script located? is it loaded (firebug > network tab)? did you include jquery itself? how did you implement the script (the html and the init of the script).. so many questions

Comment: give the path of the file and load jquery first.

Comment: yeah i found the solution, i gave the wrong path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
echo $this->Html->script(array('colorbox','new_js/abc','other_js/abc/xyz/js'));
```